# Find all instances of a text and make it a hyperlink with a macro

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, vba, macros

**Required**

I want to find all occurrences of a single text in a MS Word document, make each occurence a hyperlink and change the generic hyperlink style to one of my chosing.

**What I have**

As I have no idea on how to achieve the above requirement as a whole, I started on a part of it, namely finding a single instance and adapting it.

So, I recorded a macro, that resulted in the following code. That code I adapted so that the sub could take parameters for the *hyperlinkText* and the hyperlink *subaddress*:

```
Sub AutoDetectHyperlinksForText(hyperlinkText As String, subaddress As String, style As String)
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = hyperlinkText
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute
    ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection.Range, Address:="", _
        subaddress:=subaddress, ScreenTip:="", TextToDisplay:= _
        hyperlinkText
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles(style)
End Sub
```

With this it is easy to *Call* the sub for multiple word instances, such as:

```
Call AutoDetectHyperlinksForText("broadcasts", "_broadcastService", "Subtle Emphasis")
```

**Question**

How can I adapt this macro so that it checks the entire document?

**Bonus question**

Is there a way to modify the above script so that I can store my selection, and remove the need for the `.MoveLeft`?

In pseudocode that would be something like this:

```
Dim mySelect as Selection
mySelect = Selection.Find.Execute
ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=mySelect.Range, Address:="", _
    subaddress:=subaddress, ScreenTip:="", TextToDisplay:= _
    hyperlinkText
mySelect.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Subtle Emphasis")
```

Answer (score 1):

This will find the word "google" (not googles or googled) and hyperlink it to `http:\\google.com`

It also applies the style

```
Sub FindAndHyperlink()
    'define the style
    Dim strStyle As String
    strStyle = "Subtle Emphasis"
    'set the search range
    Dim rngSearch As Range
    Set rngSearch = ActiveDocument.Range
    'set the search string
    Dim strSearch As String
    strSearch = "google"
    'set the target address for the hyperlink
    Dim strAddress As String
    strAddress = "http:\\google.com"

    With rngSearch.Find
        Do While .Execute(findText:=strSearch, MatchWholeWord:=True, Forward:=True) = True
            With rngSearch 'we will work with what is found as it will be the selection
                ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=rngSearch, Address:=strAddress
                .Style = ActiveDocument.Styles(strStyle) 'throw the style on it after the link
            End With
            rngSearch.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
            'keep it moving
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Obviously, if you want to pass arguments you can do that so it can be called with your parameters, but this is the basis of what you'd need.