# including hyperlinks in bibliography in Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, bibliography

I am struggling to add hyperlinks in my Word-generated bibliography (I use word 2013). I came up with the following solution (I borrowed some code from Raystafarian's answer to [Find all instances of a text and make it a hyperlink with a macro](https://superuser.com/questions/1009085/find-all-instances-of-a-text-and-make-it-a-hyperlink-with-a-macro))

```
Sub Add_Hyperlinks_Bibliography()
On Error Resume Next
Set rngSearch = ActiveDocument.Range
For I = 1 To ActiveDocument.Bibliography.Sources.Count
   strStyle = "Intensieve benadrukking"
   strSearch = ActiveDocument.Bibliography.Sources.Item(I).Field("URL")
   strAddress = strSearch
   With rngSearch.Find
      Do While .Execute(findText:=strSearch) = True
          With rngSearch 'we will work with what is found as it will be the selection
              ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=rngSearch, Address:=strAddress
            .Style = ActiveDocument.Styles(strStyle) 'throw the style on it after the link
        End With
        rngSearch.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        'keep it moving
    Loop
 End With
Next I
On Error GoTo 0
Set rngSearch = Nothing
End Sub
```

This seems to work fine for most sources, but unfortunately (and I cannot explain why this happens), for some sources he does not seem to change the URL into a hyperlink. If I manually search for the URL, I do find it. Maybe anyone can explain why the code in some instances does not replace the URL by a hyperlink?

I searched the website for similar questions, and only found this thread: [Including hyperlinks in Microsoft Word 2013 references](https://superuser.com/questions/1105438/including-hyperlinks-in-microsoft-word-2013-references), which had no replies.

Comment: I got it working by changing the code "Set rngSearch = ActiveDocument.Range" into "Set rngSearch = Selection"

Comment: Fill out your profile a bit and you can submit this comment as an answer, and then accept it. This is a good thing to do because we like to see answers to problems, and you've answered your problem. Someone else may have the same issue and seeing your answer clearly marked as such will help them.